# plot a 3d point in MatLab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, point

I'm trying to plot just one point in any coordinate system: Cartesian, cylindrical or spherical.

I tried `plot3(1,1,1)` with many values but just shows a tiny point in the same location for all values! I tried `surf(X,Y,Z)` as well but matlab said: Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

Comment: did you try to read the documentation?

Comment: A plot of just one point is going to look the same in any coordinate system...

Comment: Plot a sphere with a bigger R.

Comment: @angainor yes, i've read documentation but couldn't find any clear answer!

Comment: @JosephStine i know that it is the same, so i'm looking for any function that can plot a single 3-d point! not a line/plane nor a surface

Comment: @Wli how? actually, i'm asked to convert a point from any coordinate sys. to others & plot it!

Comment: Plot3(1,1,1) is plotting a single point.  If you change the numbers, say plot3(2,2,2) the labels on the axis change.  What do you want the plot to look like?

Comment: @JosephStine but the documentation says plot3 is used for plotting a 3-d lines not a point! so you think it correct to use this function? if so, how can i make the point looks bigger/clearer than just a tiny dot.

Comment: you could type `plot3(1,1,1,'o')` and get a circle instead of a dot.  or `plot3(1,1,1,'s')` and get a square.  Look at `help plot` for more.

Comment: @JosephStine you mean 'plot3(1,1,1,'o')'

Comment: I did.  It's still just 'plot' for the help page that lists them.

Comment: @BaderSur well, plotting a sphere is straight forward if you've studied math in high school.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this?

```
plot3(1,1,1,'.');
grid on
```

[image: single point in 3d space]

You did try it, but then again, that is exactly what it does!

Comment: use `plot3(1,1,1,'.','MarkerSize',50);` for example

Answer (score 3):

Something like
scatter3(x,y,z1,720,'g','fill')
will make opaque green spheres of 720 size around all the points listed in the vectors x,y,z1.

Comment: This is a much better answer as points can be little dots that cant be seen if there are other items on the plot